# SQL BillingState != CA

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I been at this one for a few hours and am having trouble with the logic.

The question asks:
Find the playlist which have one or more tracks that have never been purchased in California (CA). Print the Id, and the name of such playlists.

The Relationship Sets can be found here:

https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation

My solutions returns nothing, and whether I am right or wrong I have no idea.
If my solution is incorrect, where is the fallacy in my logic? And if it is wrong, what is the correct way too approach this problem (Solution would be preferable with explanation)

My Solution:

```
 Select DISTINCT  P.PlaylistId, P.Name, I.BillingState
From Playlist P, Invoice I, Track T
Where  P.PlaylistId IN (
    Select PT.PlaylistId
    From PlaylistTrack PT
Where PT.TrackId IN(
    Select T.TrackId
    From Track T
    Where T.TrackId IN(
        Select IL.InvoiceLineId
        From InvoiceLine IL
        Where IL.InvoiceId IN(
            Select I.InvoiceId
            FROM Invoice I
            WHERE I.BillingState = 'CA'
            Group by I.InvoiceId
            Having COUNT(I.InvoiceId) < 1))))
Group By T.TrackId
HAVING COUNT (T.TrackId) > 1
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect? and **What** is that multi-nested query/monstrosity. Have you tried using `inner join` instead? _Please_ do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain why your code doesn't work.  (Darren has a perfectly reasonable answer.)

```
        Select I.InvoiceId
        FROM Invoice I
        WHERE I.BillingState = 'CA'
        Group by I.InvoiceId
        Having COUNT(I.InvoiceId) < 1
```

This subquery is logically flawed.  It will always return the empty set.  Why?  You are restricting the invoices to those that have `CA`.  Hence, each invoice will have at least one row before the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, the `HAVING` clause will filter everything out.

You want *conditional* aggregation:

```
        Select I.InvoiceId
        FROM Invoice I
        Group by I.InvoiceId
        Having SUM(CASE WHEN I.BillingState = 'CA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

But, you probably don't need to aggregate by `InvoiceId`.  It should be unique.  So, how about:

```
        SELECT I.InvoiceId
        FROM Invoice I
        WHERE I.BillingState <> 'CA'
```

Comment: Thank you very good explanation, was able to rewrite it and get a correct data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [`JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT PlayListId, Name
FROM PlayList PL
INNER JOIN PlayerListTrack PLT ON PLT.PlayListId = PL.PlayListId
INNER JOIN Track T ON T.Trackid = PLT.TrackId
INNER JOIN InvoiceLine IL ON IL.TrackId = T.TrackID
INNER JOIN Invoice I ON I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId
WHERE I.BillingState != 'CA'
```

This joins through all of the tables accordingly and filters out on the Invoice table (BillingState column) where the values are not equal to California.

Comment: I double checked the database and this Query returns a lot of PlayList with Tracks from BillingState of CA

Comment: @user3051442 - I don't see how that would be possible with an explicit filter on the BillingState. which would remove CA entries.